# Version automatically incrementing after entity read in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have requirement to export the data stored in Oracle database using spring boot application.
We are using **@Version** for maintaining version. When we get the data using entity and export in excel file, versions are automatically incremented by 1.

As per my knowledge when we make any changes in persisted entity then it will increment the version and persist the data. But here we are getting data for read only purpose.
Kindly help me trace the issue here.

**Code:**

```
public class BaseEntity  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name="UPDATED_BY")
    private String updatedBy;

    @Version
    @Column(name="VERSION_NO")
    private long versionNo;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdatedDate;
    
    @Column(name="DELETED")
    private Integer deleted = 0;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class ChildEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "RECORD_ID")
    private Long recordId;

    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME")
    private String displayName;

    //Some other fields 
}
```

```
public class ChildService{
    
    //repository initialization
    public void exportData(){
        List<ChildEntiy> list=repository.getChildDetails();
        for(ChildEntity child:list){
            responseDto=child.getDisplayName();
            }
    }
}
```

After this transaction complete below statement is executed.
update childEntity set last_updated_date=?, version_no=? where record_id=? and version_no=?

Comment: Simply speaking, you are persisting/merging entity somewhere.

Comment: Data is persisted in database from other source. Here I am just trying to read the data using entity. There is no setter called for retrieved entity anywhere in code. All are getters to get the value.

Comment: It may seem impossible, but the overwhelming likelihood is that something, somewhere in your code is mutating the object somehow and that the merge is happening automatically at a transaction boundary. For anyone to look into it any further, you'd have to post the relevant code.

Comment: Updated the code which explains the situation.

Comment: I still stand my ground saying you are mutating the entity. If you would show me that code of yours in `public static void main` then I could belive you, but here, this code prooves nothing as it is just a slice of bigger pie. It shows that you read your entities, but does not prove you are not modifying it somewhere else.

Comment: This isn't your real code but some dumbed down version. Please provide the actual code (maybe anonimized). So this code doesn't prove anything nor shows your actual situation. If you want help you have to provide the actual code not the cod eyou think (or want) to have.